# Unable to create chainlink function subscription using Github Repo: Chainlink Functions Starter Kit

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm trying to use Chainlink Functions using the template [Chainlink Functions Starter Kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit). I'm following along the Chainlink [Docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/getting-started). Till deploying the smart contract on Polygon Mumbai TestNet, everything goes well. But after that when I run this command: `npx hardhat functions-sub-create --network mumbai --amount 1 --contract 0xecEa1e2CAE4c38b2678217c81a17588F87f875d0`

It shows this error:

```
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version

Chainlink Functions is currently in a closed testing phase.
For access sign up here:
https://functions.chain.link
```

I'm using:
NodeJs v18.16.0

Wallet: MetaMask

Network: Polygon Mumbai TestNet
Alchemy https RPC : https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/API-KEY

I want to use Chainlink Functions to make API call that returns uint256[] (array) to my Smart Contract. Then these API calls need to be automated using Chainlink keepers. After a certain interval, CheckUpkeep needs to make one Api call which if returns a parameter as true, It needs to run the performUpKeep function to modify the Blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

The error message above provides the reason for the failed CLI command.  Currently, in order to leverage Chainlink Functions Beta on testnet, you must first apply for access.

```
For access sign up here:
https://functions.chain.link
```

*Be sure you're testing with the same wallet address you applied with!*

You can still test locally, without applying for Beta, by using the Chainlink Functions CLI command `functions-simulate`.  More information is available on [simulating functions in the docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/api-query-parameters#simulation).

Comment: Thanks ! I got the mail today about the access to chainlink functions .